# How to discard old sinals in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, bad-alloc

I have three threads: My `GUI`, an `UDPSocket` and a `worker thread`.
My `UDPSocket` is emitting a `signal` with the data to the `worker thread`.
My problem is, that my `worker thread` is running slower than the `UDPSocket` emitting `signals`, so my programm eventually runs out of memory (`bad-alloc`). Is there any possibility to discard `signals` older than x msecs or something similar? (I am getting up to 4048 UDP-Packages per 2.5 secs, packages older are not interesting anymore).

I am using Qt 4.8.6

Thank you!

Comment: Your reciver can call `blockSignals(true);` when it is near out of memory. And after it it can call `blockSignals(false);` to restore it (i.e. to continue receiving of data).

Comment: I do not think signals have an "age", but what you could do is for every signal received queue the data received and when you reach the maximum size of the queue you disconnect the signal.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause, that I do not receive any new signals? New signals are more important, than old signals.

Comment: rather than emitting so many signals which the `workerThread` can't handle, just emit the signal whenever the `workerThread` is ready. Add a signal to worker to inform when it finishes processing and ready for new data and send (emit new signal) the most recent data from the `UDPSocket` upon receiving this signal.

Comment: Thank you, that should work!